# Restore Database backup from sql file php

Tags: php

I want to make backup file to my database and then restore it .
I can create backup file but I can not restore it I don't know  why 
here is the restore code

```
$file=$_GET['restore'];
//  echo($file);
//echo $file;
        $tableNames = "";
        $fileRollback = file_get_contents($file);
 $rollBackQuery = explode("\n\n\n", $fileRollback);
  echo $fileRollback;
//echo $fileRollback;
//  $res = $con2->query($fileRollback);

$result = mysqli_multi_query($con2, $fileRollback);//or 
die(mysqli_error($con2));  
if($result)
    echo('<div class="alert-box success"><span>Success: </span>backup file 
 successfully restored.</div>');
else    echo('<div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>Faild restore 
backup file .</div>');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the restore code"? If you have a dump, just use some method to execute all MySQL queries within that dump

Comment: that what I mean with restore code but can not be restored with this above code

Comment: So which part is not working yet? You are reading data from a file, you are transferring the content to the database, so everything looks fine so far